# Different performance for default initialized and value initialized struct

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have a simple struct with an array:

```
struct A
{
  uint32_t arr[size];
};
```

I have two functions, which create it using default initialization and value initialization:

```
template<class T>
void testDefault()
{
  T* pa = new T;  // Default
  use(*pa);
  delete pa;
}

template<class T>
void testValue()
{
  T* pa = new T();  // Value
  use(*pa);
  delete pa;
}
```

I'm facing different performance for those functions. The funny thing is that performance differences vary depending on how I declare default constructor of the struct. I have three ways:

```
struct A
{
  uint32_t arr[size];
  // Implicit constructor
};

struct B
{
  uint32_t arr[size];
  B() {};  // Empty constructor
};

struct C
{
  uint32_t arr[size];
  C() = default;  // Defaulted constructor
};
```

I thought they are all the same from compiler's point of view. Never have been I so wrong. I did run both `testDefault()` and `testValue()` several times with structs `A`, `B` and `C` and measured performance. Here is what I have:

```
Default initialization (implict constructor) done in 880ms
Value initialization (implict constructor) done in 1145ms
Default initialization (empty constructor) done in 867ms
Value initialization (empty constructor) done in 865ms
Default initialization (defaulted constructor) done in 872ms
Value initialization (defaulted constructor) done in 1148ms
```

Note how performance is clearly worse for both implicit and defaulted constructors. Only empty constructor correctly shows the same performance for both different initialization forms.

I tested this with VC++, gcc and clang. See [online demo for gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd5b64d539cb9c6b). Timings are quite persistent.

What I assume is:

1. Default and value initializations for UDT are the same thing
2. All demonstrated ways of defining default constructor are doing the same thing
3. Default constructor of these structs should leave content of the array in indeterminate state

Since all the compilers exhibit the same timings, it seems like I'm missing something. Can anyone please explain me these timings?

(See also my question [Why compilers put zeros into arrays while they do not have to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188848/why-compilers-put-zeros-into-arrays-while-they-do-not-have-to) on the same topic. I give some links to cppreference there.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of *value-initialize*:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized [...];
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Also let's review the adjectives in use here for constructors:

- *user-declared* - you declared the constructor
- *user-provided* - you declared the constructor and didn't set it to `= default` or `= delete`
- *default* - can be called with no arguments
- *declared as defaulted* - marked `= default;` or implicitly generated as such

Looking at your classes:

- `A` has a default constructor which is implicitly declared as defaulted, and not user-provided.
- `C` has a default constructor which is user-declared as defaulted, and not user-provided.

So the second bullet point in the definition of value-initialize applies. The object is zero-initialized, meaning the `arr` is zeroed out.

- `B` has a default constructor which is user-provided.

So the first bullet point of value-initialize applies to `B`; value-initialization is the same as default-initialization here, and `arr` is not zeroed out.

Your timings correctly seem to correspond to what is expected: value-initialization of `A` or `C` zeroes out `arr` and the other cases don't.

Comment: note: mention of aggregates was a red herring; that only comes into play if you use list initialization.

Comment: also, I've used [,,,] to cut out the description of behaviour for classes having members of class type with non-trivial constructors , to keep it simple

Comment: Great answer! I wonder why types with no default constructor and deleted default constructor are mentioned here. Is it possible to value-initialize such classes?

Comment: @Mikhail I think that only refers to aggregates (aggregate intiialization bypasses any constructor), so `AGG agg = {};` would value-initialize there

Comment: This explains deleted default constructor. But the only other reason why a class can have no default constructor is it has other user-defined constructors. However, if a class has a user-provided constructor, it is no longer an aggregate. So you think this line refers to classes with user-defined non-default constructors that are not user-provided?

Comment: Possibly; maybe it's a catch-all of some sort

Answer (score 2):

One of the constructors behaves differently under value initialization. In this version,

```
B() {};
```

the array `B::arr` is not value-initialized when the `B` is. With the others, it is. Whether this explains the performance difference is another matter.

So, `B::arr` doesn't get zero-initialized with value initialization, whereas `A::arr` and `C::arr` do. All three cases have the same behaviour under default initialization, that is to say, `arr` gets *default-initialized*, i.e. no initialization is performed.

Comment: Why does the explicitly defaulted constructor do smth. different than the empty one? There is no aggregate initialization going on here, isn't it?

Comment: @BaummitAugen That's a good question. Probably because it tries to be as close to the compiler synthesized one as possible. Before `default`, it was not possible to get back that behaviour wrt. default and value initialization.